# Implement same action with for loop in JS

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have the next lines of code,

```
var seats = []


    for (a = 0; a <= seatsNumFront; a++) {
        seats.push(new Seat((a * xPad) + 300, 60, 30, 30, id++, "A", a, "#998515"))
    }
    for (b = 0; b <= seatsNumFront; b++) {
        seats.push(new Seat((b * xPad) + 300, 100, 30, 30, id++, "B", b, "#998515"))
    }
    for (c = 0; c <= seatsNumFront; c++) {
        seats.push(new Seat((c * xPad) + 300, 140, 30, 30, id++, "C", c, "#998515"))
    }
```

I want to achieve that those lines will be executed according to a value that I will defined.

For example:
I want to assign number to a variable and write this line only one time and execute it according to my variable

So let say i will write:

```
var seats = []
var num = 3

    for (c = 0; c <= seatsNumFront; c++) {
        seats.push(new Seat((c * xPad) + 300, 140, 30, 30, id++, "C", c, "#998515"))
    }
```

Wanted result:

```
var seats = []
var num = 3

for (a = 0; a <= seatsNumFront; a++) {
    seats.push(new Seat((a * xPad) + 300, 60, 30, 30, id++, "A", a, "#998515"))
}
for (b = 0; b <= seatsNumFront; b++) {
    seats.push(new Seat((b * xPad) + 300, 100, 30, 30, id++, "B", b, "#998515"))
}
for (c = 0; c <= seatsNumFront; c++) {
    seats.push(new Seat((c * xPad) + 300, 140, 30, 30, id++, "C", c, "#998515"))
}
```

Comment: By the number of downvotes, I am guessing I am not the only one that has no idea what you are asking. No clue what "3" has to do with the code.

Comment: We need more context/detail. Add some more and ill be able to provide an answer for you. I know for sure you want to use a function though.

Comment: @epascarello I have an idea - maybe he wants one nested loop to do those and actually intended to use e.g. `let a = 0`, and the loop counters are not declared somewhere else.

Comment: @epascarello Sorry about that , I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't entirely get what you want here, but I know you want to write a function.
Here is example code that would put your for loop in a function using two parameters.

Edit: Based on your elaboration I have added more code.

```
//Variables in your code, dont worry about these.
var id = 0;  
var seatsNumFront = 1;
var seats = Array();
var xPad = 5

//Function to add seats based on the value (60,100,140 in your question) and a character ('A', 'B', 'C' in your question)
function addSeats(value, ch){
    for(var i = 0;i <= seatsNumFront;i++)
        seats.push(new Seat((i * xPad) + 300, value, 30, 30, id++, ch, i, "#998515"));   
}


var num = 3, start = 60, diff = 40, ch = 'A';
for(var i = 0;i < num;i++){
              //60 + (40 * i)
    addSeats(start + (diff * i),  ch++);
}
//The for-loop above will put seats in with the following parameters (60, 'A'), (100, 'B'), (140, 'C').
```

The above code ought to work with any `positive` values for `num`.

Comment: Brilliant. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you parameterize your push statement, you can pass values in as needed.
I used your c forloop example and added a switch case. There are other ways to do it, but the point is to write the for loop only once.

This is a verbose example of what you might be looking to achieve:

```
var num = 3
var param1 = 0;
var param2 = "";

for (x = 0; x <= seatsNumFront; x++) {
    switch (num) {
        case 1:
            param1 = 60;
            param2 = "A";
            break;
        case 2:
            param1 = 100;
            param2 = "B";
            break;
        case 3:
            param1 = 140;
            param2 = "C";
            break;
        default:
    }
    //seats.push(new Seat((c * xPad) + 300, 140, 30, 30, id++, "C", c, "#998515"))
    seats.push(new Seat((x * xPad) + 300, param1, 30, 30, id++, param2, x, "#998515"))
}
```

In this example, if num equals 3 then the resulting for loop will process the same as this:

```
seats.push(new Seat((c * xPad) + 300, 140, 30, 30, id++, "C", c, "#998515"))
```

By setting the param1 value to 140 and the param2 value to "C". If num equaled 2 then it would use 100 and "B" respectively.

Comment: I guess I was late to the game. By the time I posted this and read the other responses. I saw that @Zachary Jones had already updated his answer with the same jist.